# `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)` after `gdal.RasterizeLayer`

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I get this error when I run this:

```
vector_layer = "mask.shp"
raster_layer = "raster.tif"
target_layer = "mask.tif"

# open the raster layer and get its relevant properties
raster_ds = gdal.Open(raster_layer, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
xSize = raster_ds.RasterXSize
ySize = raster_ds.RasterYSize
geotransform = raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()
projection = raster_ds.GetProjection()

# create the target layer (1 band)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
target_ds = driver.Create(target_layer, xSize, ySize, bands=1, eType=gdal.GDT_Byte)

target_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
target_ds.SetProjection(projection)

# rasterize the vector layer into the target one
ds = gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], ogr.Open(vector_layer).GetLayer(), burn_values=[1])

target_ds = None
```

It happens when I call `target_ds = None` after `RasterizeLayer`. If I don't run `RasterizeLayer` it does not fail. So what I am trying to do is create a mask of the polygons in `mask.shp` using the projection and geotransform information from `raster.tif`.

Note I am using gdal version `1.10.1`.

Comment: You cannot use **ogr.Open(vector_layer).GetLayer()** inside 'RasterizeLayer' gdal method as parameter. This produces 'Segmentation fault'.

Comment: Please, see my **Editing Note**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use **ogr.Open(vector_layer).GetLayer()** inside 'RasterizeLayer' gdal method as parameter. This produces 'Segmentation fault'. So, I used following version of your script (with paths to my test layers) and it works perfectly.

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

vector_layer = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/cut_polygon3.shp"
raster_layer = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/aleatorio.tif"
target_layer = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/mask.tif"

# open the raster layer and get its relevant properties
raster_ds = gdal.Open(raster_layer, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
xSize = raster_ds.RasterXSize
ySize = raster_ds.RasterYSize
geotransform = raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()
projection = raster_ds.GetProjection()

# create the target layer (1 band)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
target_ds = driver.Create(target_layer, xSize, ySize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

target_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
target_ds.SetProjection(projection)
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_layer)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()

# rasterize the vector layer into the target one
ds = gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[1])

target_ds = None
```

Mask shapefile and raster layer look like as follow:

[image]

After running script at Python Console, rasterized shapefile is showed at following image:

[image]

It works.

**Editing Note:**

Based on your comment and Luke's, for this case you can use following similar code:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

vector_layer = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/cut_polygon4.shp"
raster_layer = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/aleatorio.tif"
target_layer = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/mask.tif"

# open the raster layer and get its relevant properties
raster_ds = gdal.Open(raster_layer, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
xSize = raster_ds.RasterXSize
ySize = raster_ds.RasterYSize
geotransform = raster_ds.GetGeoTransform()
projection = raster_ds.GetProjection()

# create the target layer (1 band)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
target_ds = driver.Create(target_layer, xSize, ySize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

target_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
target_ds.SetProjection(projection)
source_ds = ogr.Open(vector_layer)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer()

# rasterize the vector layer into the target one
ds = gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer, options = ["ATTRIBUTE=value"])

target_ds = None
```

My test layers now look like (vectorial layer has 'value' field; where burn values are):

[image]

After running code, resulting rasterized layer looks like at following image:

[image]

With **Value Tool** QGIS plugin, I corroborated that each feature had adequate burn value.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you mentioned *why* the segfault occurs. Perhaps link to the gdal python gotchas page that explains it in detail.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to get each individual polygon so I can burn a different value for each and get seperate instances?

Comment: @JustinLiang You can do that by specifying an attribute field to use as the burn value. It's in the (very limited) documentation. If you need further help, ask a new question.

Comment: What will be the value of  variable ds here, does it contain the rasterized dataset ?

Comment: Yes, ds is the rasterized vector layer.